# How to extend generic type by field?

Tags: typescript

I try to use generic type:

```
export abstract class Tree<T extends { children?: T[] }> {
}
```

So, I want to specify that generic type T always has children propetry:

```
T extends { children?: T[] }
```

Is it good approach to do that?

Comment: I think you'd be better off making a class with the property children and then stating that T extends that.  Tree<T extends MyChildrenClass }>

Comment: So, like this? `class MyChildrenClass<T> { children: T[]; }`?

Comment: How then to use it? `class TreeMap<T> extends Tree<T> {}`

Comment: Without the "<T>"     class MyChildrenClass { children: T[]; }

Comment: But what is T in children class. You can't use T to define T. You get a logical loop

Comment: So, children can has different object type but only one property is required: children. What is type should be for `children: any[]`?

Comment: That's up to you to decide. I don't know what children is supposed to represent. number/string/any etc. It just can't be T because you are using the children's class to define T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export interface Branch {
  name: string;
  children: Branch[]
}

export class Tree<T extends Branch> {
  constructor(public root: T) {}
}

export class BranchImpl implements Branch {
  children: BranchImpl[] = [];
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}

const branch0 = new BranchImpl("root");
const branch1 = new BranchImpl("branch1");
branch0.children.push(branch1);
branch0.children.push(new BranchImpl("branch2"));
branch1.children.push(new BranchImpl("branch3"));
console.log(new Tree<BranchImpl>(branch0));
```

You can use the interface Branch to define tree children and class Tree to wrap root branch.